# get_the_term_list( get_the_ID() label formatting?

Tags: terms, formatting, labels

is it possible to change the style of the "label" of the result of a get_the_term_list( get_the_ID() ?

```
    $film_tags = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'film_tags', 'Tags: ', ', ', '' );
```

is there a way to have (in the results) the "Tags: " in bold?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML to mark it up however you'd like. You can use a `<strong>` tag to make it bold:

```
$film_tags = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'film_tags', '<strong>Tags:</strong> ', ', ', '' );
```

Or add a class to style with CSS:

```
$film_tags = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'film_tags', '<span class="tags-label">Tags:</span> ', ', ', '' );
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried both, but somehow they don't work ...
thanks anyway